# ignore function after x seconds powerbuilder

Tags: function, timeout, powerbuilder

I'm newbie in powerbuilder.
I have this function from DLL library

FUNCTION long GET_SERVICE_FILE(param list..) LIBRARY "PB_GET_SERVICE_DATA.dll" alias for "GET_SERVICE_FILE;Ansi"

I don't write that so i don't know what is it doing. After call function, a txt file created. Maybe it get data from database and wirte to TXT file.

My problem: sometime that function cannot finish (longtime execute without message/error) and hang up my app.

My question: is it possible setting time waiting for function execute? after time period, ignore function and go to next step.

Thanks and best regards.

Loc Nguyen.

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing that’s built-in that does this auto-magically. You’d have to build your own using multitasking functionality. Once you’ve dug into some of the issues like “after you pass the 15 seconds, what do you do when the function eventually returns?” I suspect you’ll recognize this has a few challenges.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider posting the function instead of calling it:
Instead of

```
My_function(parm1,...)
```

Use

```
POST My_function(parm1,...)
sleep(4)
```